# How to remove parent category from subcategory URL?

Tags: magento2, category, url, url-rewrite

I want to remove the parent category from the subcategory URL.

For example, I would like to change:

```
www.magento2.com/Category1/Category2/gear/bags.html
```

to

```
www.magento2.com/bags.html
```

Is there any way to programmatically remove parent category from subcategory URL?

Comment: So, what happens if `www.magento2.com/bag1/bag2/bag3.html`?

Comment: www.magento2.com/bag3.html

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the class `Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator` which is responsible for the category URL rewrite generation, you will see that it uses a constant value to determine if the parent path should be added:

```
protected function isNeedToGenerateUrlPathForParent($category)
{
    return $category->isObjectNew() || $category->getLevel() >= self::MINIMAL_CATEGORY_LEVEL_FOR_PROCESSING;
}
```

The value is

```
const MINIMAL_CATEGORY_LEVEL_FOR_PROCESSING = 3;
```

which means the path is generated for every category that is not a top category (level 1 is the root category) and you cannot configure this value or turn off parent path generation.

And since it is a protected method we cannot modify the return value with a plugin. Instead you will have to write a plugin for the public method `getUrlPath()` that uses `isNeedToGenerateUrlPathForParent()`.

I would use an *around* plugin which does not call the original method, essentially replacing the method:

```
class RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin
{
    public function aroundGetUrlPath($subject, $proceed, $category)
    {
        if (in_array($category->getParentId(), [Category::ROOT_CATEGORY_ID, Category::TREE_ROOT_ID])) {
            return '';
        }
        $path = $category->getUrlPath();
        if ($path !== null && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('url_key') && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('parent_id')) {
            return $path;
        }
        $path = $category->getUrlKey();
        if ($path === false) {
            return $category->getUrlPath();
        }
        return $path;
    }
}
```

(this is the original method, but without the parent path generation)

**Plugin documentation:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

#### Update existing categories

This will apply for new categories. Unfortunately the category URLs are not generated by an indexer anymore, so reindexing does not change them and the only way to regenerate them is to save each category. It could be done with a one-off script that loads a collection of all categories and calls `save()` on it:

```
$allCategories = $categoryCollectionFactory->create()->load();
foreach ($allCategories as $category) {
    $category->setDataChanges(true);
    $category->save();
}
```

Note that this is not optimized for performance at all and will load all categories at once. So if you have thousands of categories you might want to process them in batches.

Comment: I tried to create the plugin, but doesn't seems to have any effect.
for example - I have created a file `RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin.php` in `Myweb/RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin/plugin/` and created `di.xml` in etc folder with contents like `
    <type name="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model">
        <plugin name="Myweb_RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin" type="Myweb\RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin\Plugin\RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin" />
    </type>

Comment: in addition to above I have created the `registration.php` and `module.xml`. Also created some new child categories, but still parent categories show up.

Comment: Hi Fabian - can you take a look at - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232750/magento2-plugin-to-remove-parent-category/232751#232751 - what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php around line 75
```

comment out these lines under the function `getUrlPath($category)` i.e.

```
/* if ($this->isNeedToGenerateUrlPathForParent($category)) {
            $parentPath = $this->getUrlPath(
                $this->categoryRepository->get($category->getParentId(), $category->getStoreId())
            );
            $path = $parentPath === '' ? $path : $parentPath . '/' . $path;
            $path = '';

        } */
```

And then reindex and clean up the cache. Also, Don't forget to re-save the categories (that were created prior to making the above mentioned edits).

> Is code concept is not correct because after importing removing parent category it is not possible and
>   Overriding CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php makes error in product importing.

This is not advisable

Answer (score -1):

for getting rid of category name from subcategory URL you need to edit the ---

`vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/CategoryUrlPathGenerator.php` around line 75

comment out these lines under the function `getUrlPath($category)` 
i.e.

```
/* if ($this->isNeedToGenerateUrlPathForParent($category)) {
            $parentPath = $this->getUrlPath(
                $this->categoryRepository->get($category->getParentId(), $category->getStoreId())
            );
            $path = $parentPath === '' ? $path : $parentPath . '/' . $path;
            $path = '';

        } */
```

And then reindex and clean up the cache. Also Don't forget to re-save the categories (that were created prior to making the above mentioned edits).

Comment: so the solution works maybe you could have mentioned it's -1ed for reformatting the text.