# Magento2 Plugin to remove Parent category

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Referring the answer to this question - [How to remove parent category from subcategory URL?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134988/how-to-remove-parent-category-from-subcategory-url)
I created the file in Module Plugin folder - `RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin.php` with contents like:

```
<?php
namespace Myweb\RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin\Plugin;

class RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin
{
    public function aroundGetUrlPath($subject, $proceed, $category)
    {
        if (in_array($category->getParentId(), [Category::ROOT_CATEGORY_ID, Category::TREE_ROOT_ID])) {
            return '';
        }
        $path = $category->getUrlPath();
        if ($path !== null && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('url_key') && !$category->dataHasChangedFor('parent_id')) {
            return $path;
        }
        $path = $category->getUrlKey();
        if ($path === false) {
            return $category->getUrlPath();
        }
        return $path;
    }
}
```

also added `di.xml` in `etc` folder with contents like:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model">
        <plugin name="Myweb_RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin" type="Myweb\RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin\Plugin\RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and `module.xml` in `etc` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Myweb_RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin" setup_version="1.0.1" />
</config>
```

and `registration.php` in module folder with contents:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Myweb_RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin',
__DIR__
);
```

What I am missing here. as the plugin doesn't seems to have any effect.
I tried to create new category as well to see if it works on new category.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your **di.xml** like below:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator">
        <plugin name="Myweb_RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin" type="Myweb\RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin\Plugin\RemoveParentCategoryPathPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

You have missed the class name in your di.xml.

Run the following command after the change:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Hi Sukumar - Thanks for your help. When I am running the command `setup:di:compile` I am getting the error from other module `ccavenue_pay` like ` [ReflectionException]
  Class Magento\Ccavenuepay\Helper\Hss does not exist` I have disabled that module temporarily, but I am still getting this error. how I can overcome that.

Comment: Copy that module from your magento2 installation to outside and delete the ccavenue from magento2 then run the command.

Comment: Thanks I did just that. and was able to run the command "setup:di:compile". Now when I am saving an existing category I am getting the error like - `something went wrong while saving the category` and if I am creating a new category some more info with the same error like `Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/wwwindianartzone/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 102` . Any idea why I am getting that error.

Comment: This issue is something different.

Comment: You mean it is not related to the code example I have added in the question.

Comment: Can you disable the plugin for testing then run di compile and test again

Comment: Yes. after disabling the plugin and running the di compile the error goes away. can you please help me address this?

Comment: Enable the plugin again. run di compile then run reindex. And see if errr still occurs or not.

Comment: Now that additional error is not showing. but still getting the error `Something went wrong while saving the category.`

Comment: Check log file.

Comment: Also check the url if they are saving correctly or not.

Comment: The category is not getting saved at all, after enabling the plugin. only that error.

Comment: Its showing class doesn't exist, check the plugin path is correct or not.

Comment: the name of plugin folder is in small-case `plugin`. could this be the reason it is not able to locate?

Comment: Change it to Plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79876/discussion-between-joshi-and-sukumar-gorai).